# ANTLR4 CPP14 Grammar not able to identify decimal numbers

Tags: c++, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I am using the below ANTLR grammar for parsing my code.

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/cpp

The following code gives error while parsing. Here "08" is not identifying as an integer literal.

```
TEST_F(suite_name_test_p, 08)
{
   //...
}
```

I have made the following changes to fix this error:

```
 Decimalliteral
  //: NONZERODIGIT ('\''? DIGIT)*  //old 
    : NONZERODIGIT* ('\''? DIGIT)+  // changed to     
 ;
```

But with these changes, octal numbers are getting identified as an integer literal. Any other changes suggested?

Comment: You could rewrite the octal rule, which you haven't shown, such that illegal octal literals are interpreted as decimal, but you really don't want to do that: you want to flag it as an error. Otherwise the meaning of the program text becomes too obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers starting with 0 are in octal, base 8, hence are allowed only the digits 0-7, every digit representing 3 bits.

So in your case 08 contains an illegal digit, 8.

---

*As you seem to be aware of this, but may be want to remove octal numbers altogether from a non-C++ compliant grammar:*

I did not read the grammar, but somewhere there must be an alternative with IntegerLiteral and "OctalLiteral". The octal alternative must be removed to entirely remove octal numbers from the language.